# Windows 2008 Server Std and Exchange 2003

Tags: windows-server-2008, installation, exchange-2003

Is it possible to install Exchange 2003 on a 2008 Server?

I am trying to do this, but am facing all sorts of problems, such as the installer quitting before doing anything.

Just wanted to know that this was ok to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exchange 2003 is not supported on Windows Server 2008. Even Exchange 2007 was not supported on Windows Server 2008 until Exchange 2007 SP1 came along.

See [KB948680: Description of the Microsoft server applications that are supported on Windows Server 2008](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/948680).

Comment: Ah - I notice that Exchange 2007 is only available in 64bit... Not good if I've got Windows 2008 Server 32bit installed! So, am I right in thinking that if I've got 32bit version of 2008 installed, then I can't run any version of Exchange?

Comment: Yes and no. There is a 32-bit version of Exchange 2007, but Microsoft do not support anything but 64-bit for production deployments. The 32-bit version is good for testing purposes in a pre-production scenario. You can also use the 32-bit version to install the Exchange management functionality on 32-bit machines, even in a production environment, as long as the Exchange server/s are 64-bit.

Comment: That's exactly what I want it for - I wanted to create a test environment but couldn't because of the 64 bit version of Exchange and the 32 bit version of Server 2008 that we have.

Can I download that 32bit version from somewhere? I have all relevant licenses to cover it, but no media to install from.

Comment: SP1 here: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=44c66ad6-f185-4a1d-a9ab-473c1188954c&displaylang=en, and SP2 here: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=44c66ad6-f185-4a1d-a9ab-473c1188954c&displaylang=en. Both of these can be used to perform a clean installation of Exchange 2007.